# Do the entries in all vectors grow at most the value of the spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let **T** $\in \mathbb{R}^{92,92}$ with all non-negative entrys 
Let *y* be the spectral radius and **v**$_y$ a corresponding eigenvector then we know
*y* **v**$_y$=**T** **v**$_y$   =>   *y*$^n$ **v**$_y$=**T**$^n$ **v**$_y$
so the non zero entry's of **T**$^n$ **v**$_y$ are proportional to *y*$^n$

How would you prove that the entries in all other images of any vector **v** grow at most at this rate, and also if we take a basis for the space which **T** projects into that at least one of the basis vectors entries increase at *y*

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ has non-negative entries, but doesn't have a positive spectral radius.  Also, spectral radius typically refers to the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue, though that doesn't make a difference in this case.  Also, it's **entries**, not **entry's**.

Comment: In any case, [Gelfand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand.27s_Formula) gives you the desired bound on the entries of $\mathbf T^n \mathbf v$

Comment: Sorry but how does Gelfand thm show this

Comment: The key is that if $\rho$ is the spectral radius, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \|T^n v\|^{1/n} \leq \rho
$$
for every $v$, which tells us that for some $C>0$, we have
$$
\|T^nv\| \leq C\rho^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Not always true:
$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&2&0\\0&0&2\\0&0&0\end{array}\right)
$$
All the eigenvalues of $T$ are zero, and so is its spectral radius.

Then
$$
T\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\2\\0\end{array}\right), \quad
T^2\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c} 4\\0\\0\end{array}\right).
$$